# In `data.table` within R, is there a fast way to combine tables together?

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently looking for a way to combine several tables together which have the same structure and column names. For example, I would like to combine these three tables:

```
>dt1
user     number
A        32
A        33
A        35
A        23
A        32
A        44
A        33

>dt2
user     number
B        32
B        33
B        35
B        23
B        32
B        44
B        33

>dt3
user     number
C        32
C        33
C        35
C        23
C        32
C        44
C        33
```

and get:

```
>dt_combined
user     number
A        32
A        33
A        35
A        23
A        32
A        44
A        33
B        32
B        33
B        35
B        23
B        32
B        44
B        33
C        32
C        33
C        35
C        23
C        32
C        44
C        33
```

I have been trying to use either join or merge, but as simple as this problem is, I can't seem to pinpoint the fast and easy solution within data.table. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `rbind`?

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged this as `data.table`, which has a convenient function `rbindlist`.

You can use it in conjunction with `mget`, like this:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "dt\\d")))
```

The `mget` step creates a `list` of the objects in your workspace matching a naming pattern like `dt1`, `dt2`, and so on (`dt` + "digits"). `rbindlist` takes that list and makes it into one big `data.table`.

---

```
> print(rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "dt\\d"))), topn = 3)
    user number
 1:    A     32
 2:    A     33
 3:    A     35
---            
19:    C     32
20:    C     44
21:    C     33
```